# File exists or not in unix

Tags: sh

I am trying to check whether a file exists or not and written the status to another status file.

```
CD=$1

if [ ls FILE_${CD}01.TXT -eq FILE_${CD}01.TXT ]; then echo "ok">status.text; 
else 
echo "not ok" >status.text; fi
```

Help me correct the syntax please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-f` flag to `[`:

```
if [ -f "FILE_${CD}01.TXT" ]; then
    echo ok > status.text
else
    echo not ok > status.text
fi
```

Comment: If `$CD` can contain spaces, you may consider quoting the filename: `[ -f "FILE_${CD}01.TXT" ]` to prevent word-splitting.

Comment: Since the value of `CD` is out of the control of the script, it *should* be quoted.

Comment: The given code is incorrect. You can force the condition to be true by passing any string ending in ` -o ` for the value of `$1`.

Comment: Note that `-f` tells you whether the target is a "regular" file. If it exists, but it's a directory, or a named pipe, or something else, `-f` will be false. You can use `-e` to test whether it exists (true for files, directories, named pipes, etc.)